# can we have anchors in alerts?

Tags: javascript

I want to throw an alert message if a user enters a bad username/password and give users an option to hit "ok" which lets them try the page again or "forgot password" which lets them go to a different link to change their password.

Can I use an alert box and add an anchor to it ? I don't want to have a button floating around until someone enters a wrong password.

Comment: sidenote: _`alert` should not be used in production code._

Comment: @c69: I agree with you in theory, but sometimes, you just want a good ol' fashioned simple alert! And pragmatism has to win over slavish ivory-tower rule following I think. A blanket statement like 'never' is rarely helpful or correct

Comment: @Java Drinker: 'should not' != 'never'

Comment: @c69: Fair enough, I may have staw-man'd ur statement... apologies please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `confirm()`.

This function shows a message followed by a *Ok* and *Cancel* buttons:

```
if (confirm('You used a wrong password; Would you like to retrieve your password ?')) {
    document.location = 'retrieve the password';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. `alert()` boxes can only display plain text. If you wanted to create your own pop-up box like that you would need to implement it yourself, you couldn't use `alert()`.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `alert` function won't show hypertext, just text.  You can use a fancier implementation from any one of the popular Javascript gui libraries.  They will let you create an HTML pop-up instead.

Answer (score 1):

`alert` does not display HTML.  You'll have to emit markup to display the message instead.  There are many libraries that can do this for you, including jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You can use the [showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog) function instead. See the demo at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/showModalDialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to show the user a custom message. You may want to use absolutely positioned DIV element, a modal dialog window or an iframe for that purpose.